# Images are not showed

Tags: reactjs

I'm using create-react-app, and when I build my project for production purposes, I have a problem displaying assets which are called from SCSS files.

Here's my build hierarchy:

```
    - index.html
    - assets/
        - arrow2.svg
    - static/
        - css/
        - js/
```

Styles.scss:

```
&.card {
    background: $green700;
    border-color: $green700;
    color: #fff;
    &:after{
        background-image: url("/assets/arrow2.svg");
    }
```

package.json contains `"homepage": "."`

With the current `background-image` value I have no error and it's working locally, but not on my server.

Pretty sure I messed up something with the settings somewhere.

Edit: I want to point out the problem better. Currently, The server is asking the image from this url:
`http://server.com/assets/arrow2.svg` 
but the actual app is located at `/react-app` and therefore the image should be taken relatively from:
`http://server.com/react-app/assets/arrow2.svg`

When I try using `./assets/arrow2.svg` in style.scss I get an error that the file can't be located and can't run build.

Comment: where is your styles.scss file located?

Comment: you can hover over the image src in the class inspector and see the image preview?

Comment: @tdammon my style.scss is located in `src`

Comment: I've added more information explaining the problem

Comment: Okay. If your app is ejected. I may help you here

Comment: On first thought, question is `why is your app inside react-app`. If you DO want this for some reason. You need to change some configuration for which you NEED to eject. If you do so, remember it's a one time process. You may want to play around with a copy of the project to experiment this

Comment: my app is inside react-app because this is where I want it to live. It's not the default I want to show when you enter the server. Not sure what you mean by eject though.

Comment: Are you using Heroku?

Comment: Not using Heroku. I use `npm run build` as explained on the documentation of create-react-app, and upload it to my server.

Answer (score 0):

Photos need to be in "Public" folder if you're using Git or Heroku.

Comment: They are currently in `Public`.